# Is the default MTU for Android 14 now 517 bytes?

Tags: android, mtu

Is the default MTU for Android 14 now 517 bytes or is it still 23 bytes? If the former, it may be problematic for Bluetooth chips that lack MTU negotiation.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all

~I now understand that the default MTU value (23) has not changed under Android 14. Thank you to all who provided feedback and trust that others will find utility in the commentary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specification only allows one MTU negotiation per connection. Previously, every client holding a BluetoothGatt object could request its own MTU. Android previously ignored the spec and re-negotiated the MTU on every MTU request. Allowing custom MTUs does not play well in a shared environment, where multiple independent apps talks to the same BLE device. If one app first negotiates MTU=25 since it does not need more, but the other app wants to (later) negotiate MTU=500, it can't do that if the spec is to be followed.

Therefore, now Android selects an MTU which should be good enough for most use cases (517) the first time a client wants to negotiate MTU. An MTU of 517 makes sure the longest GATT value (512 bytes) can be sent in one L2CAP packet for most types of commands/requests/notifications.

I don't see why this would break pre 4.2 BLE devices. Nothing about the MTU or GATT packet lengths has been changed in any version of BLE. Devices that don't support a higher MTU than the default (23) will keep using 23 and devices that support a higher MTU than 23 but lower than 517 will negotiate that value.

**Edit:**

I decided to test what happens when the remote device does not support MTU Exchange. Per the specification (all BLE versions), an error response should be sent to an Exchange MTU Request, containing the error code "Request Not Supported".

When the Android app calls `requestMtu` with some arbitrary MTU as parameter, see this btmon log what packets are exchanged:

```
> ACL Data RX: Handle 3585 flags 0x02 dlen 7
      ATT: Exchange MTU Request (0x02) len 2
        Client RX MTU: 517
< ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x00 dlen 9
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Exchange MTU Request (0x02)
        Handle: 0x0000
        Error: Request Not Supported (0x06)
```

The callback `onMtuChanged` is then called, with the parameters mtu=23 and status=6 (Request Not Supported). The MTU therefore continues to be the default (23).

However, I noticed a bug in Android (Pixel 7 running Android 14) that happens if any BluetoothGatt client tries to call `requestMtu` after a previous `requestMtu` called by any BluetoothGatt client (possibly another) has resulted in the error "Request Not Supported". At this point, no `onMtuChanged` callback will be called, and no other GATT operations seem to work on this BluetoothGatt object, e.g. calling `readCharacteristic` never sends any Read Request nor is any response callback called. This bad state is present until the device disconnects.

Comment: "I don't see why this would break pre 4.2 BLE devices": Pre 4.2 BLE modules do not have the capability of returning a requested MTU (this was back when the only packet size was 23 bytes).  As a result, the default Android MTU (517) is persisted.  This is right from Android docs: "Your peripheral device should respond to the Android device's MTU request with a reasonable value that can be accommodated by the peripheral. The final negotiated value will be a minimum of the Android requested value and the remote provided value (i.e. min(517, remoteMtu))"

Comment: Correction:  This would just break pre 4.2 BLE modules without MTU negotiation capabilities (as is the case with our module).

Comment: "Exchange MTU" has always been an optional feature, even pre-4.2. Nothing changed in version 4.2. However it could be that your module does not support the Exchange MTU feature (since it is optional). In that case, Android will not change the MTU but leave it at the default (23). Is this not what you see? Do you get an `onMtuChanged` callback with the `mtu` parameter set to 517?

Comment: In regards to the peripheral application layer I do not have access to this, but do not believe it was ever configured to coordinate MTU exchange. I take it you are suggesting that when the MTU request from Android times out (peripheral not able to respond) Android should automatically sets the MTU size to 23?  I do not see this indicated in the documentation.   I am doing some Wireshark tests and will let you know what I find.  Thank you for your help!  Our application works as expected in an Android 13 environment (and earlier).

Comment: "Android will not change the MTU but leave it at the default (23)":  My understanding is that the default is now 517 in Android 14.

Comment: No, 517 is what Android _requests_. "The final negotiated value will be a minimum of the Android requested value and the remote provided value (i.e. min(517, remoteMtu))"

Comment: In my case the remote provided value is never provided.  From the behavior I am observing the value used by Android 14 at this point is 517.  Please supply any documentation you are aware of if this is not the case.  Again, our system works fine Android 13 and prior.

Comment: I just tried with a device that does not support the Exchange MTU feature. As expected, `onMtuChanged` is called with mtu set to 23 (not 517). The status parameter contains the error code "Request Not Supported". If you see that `onMtuChanged` is called with mtu=517 and status=0 (success), then your device supports MTU exchange with 517 as MTU value. I put the details as an edit to my post.

Comment: It must be called at least once by any BluetoothGatt client for each connection in order for MTU Exchange to take place (unless the remote side sends it I guess). Otherwise the MTU will remain at the default (23). Maybe you see the same bug I saw? Do you send the requestMtu request more than once?

Comment: Thanks!  It appears that we may in fact be requesting this more than once, and we were observing the communication failure on a pixel phone with Android 14.  Thank you for the lead!

Comment: Quick question, was the Android app you tested built for Android 14 (targetSdkVersion 34)?  We have no issues when targeting 33.  Thanks!

Comment: targetSdk is 34

Comment: Thank you very much for double checking this and for all your help.  I need to double down and look elsewhere for root of our problem.